# How do you find and load an autosaved level in the Portal 2 Test Chamber editor?

Tags: portal-2

I was working on a level, hit save, quit, and after returning to the editor the level was in a previously saved state.  Is there a way I can check if there's an autosave file containing these changes and load it?

Comment: I dont think auto saves are made, and if they are, most likely they are made with each map build. If you go to your portal 2 folder, the most likely place for auto saves would be : \Steam\SteamApps\common\portal 2\portal2_dlc2\maps

The folder your looking for should have in it at least one .bsp file

Comment: Autosaves are being made. I've had the problem before, where I clicked the save button and then quit, where it told me the app told me I quit too soon, and the program didn't have a chance to save it, but it had an autosave, and asked me if I wanted to load that. I always did, and it looked like the version I actually tried to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go into your workshop levels and then you should see your autosave if not it is probably in single player or co-op levels depending on what type of map your making